# Getting xml as response rather than as JSON for Solr

Tags: solr

Getting xml response instead of JSON response from Solr index records
I am getting xml as response for the query string and i wanted to have json format .

I have set **wt=json** while passing to query string.I am writing in scala code to get data from solr via **REST API**.

Here is my code.

```
val qp = s"""full-name:"Jon Snow"""" +"&"+ "wt=json"
    buf = buf.append(URLEncoder.encode(qp  , "UTF-8") + "&")
    val queryparams = buf.toString
    val queryString = queryparams.substring(0, queryparams.length() - 1);
    val urlEncoded: String `enter code here`="http://solr:8983/solr/lily_entity_APPLICATION_shard1_replica1/select?q=" + queryString;

val connection = (new [enter image description here][1]URL(urlEncoded)).openConnection.asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]
      connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
      val inputStream = connection.getInputStream
       val content = Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).mkString
```

Plz help

Comment: This is working as i have properly parsed/Encoded the wt=json whcih results in json format.

Comment: This is working as i have properly parsed/Encoded the wt=json whcih results in json format.